# How to assign the lowest possible number which is not already assigned

Tags: javascript, algorithm, numbers

What I am doing is dynamically creating elements and appending them to the page. The elements need to have an `id`, so I assign each of them a numerical `id` when the element is created. However, elements can and will be removed in a non-linear fashion, so you can end up having gaps between values like so...

*One hypothetical scenario: `1`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `16`, `22`.*

*In the case above, if I were to create an element, I would want to assign `2` as its `id`.*

*Another hypothetical scenario: `3`, `4`, `5`.*

*In this case, `1` should be assigned as the `id`.*

I have written the code below, which should work fine, but I feel like it is unnecessarily complex. **Does anybody have any idea how to improve upon it?!**

```
const divs = element.getElementsByTagName('div')
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  if (i > 0 && Number(divs[i].id) > Number(divs[i-1].id)+1 ) {
    return Number(divs[i-1].id)+1
    break
  } else if (i === divs.length-1) {
    return Number(divs[divs.length-1].id)+1
  } else if (Number(divs[0].id) > 1) {
    return 1
    break
  } else if (divs.length === 1 && Number(divs[0].id) === 1) {
    return 2
  } else if (divs.length === 1 && Number(divs[0].id) !== 1) {
    return 1
  }
}
```

I've chosen to take elsyr's advice and track the IDs. This will allow me to implement the following code, which is optimal given the circumstances.

```
const lowestNum = lowestId()
div.id = lowestNum
numericalIds[lowestNum-1] = lowestNum

function lowestId(){
  for (let i = 0; i < numericalIds.length; i++) {
    if (!numericalIds[i]) {
      return i+1
    } else if (i === numericalIds.length-1) {
      return numericalIds[numericalIds.length-1]+1
    }
  }
  return 1
}
```

I simply have to update the array right before elements are removed from the page.

```
numericalIds[/*numerical value of id*/-1] = 0 // or null or undefined
```

This will always create IDs with the smallest numerical value that is not already assigned and is no smaller than `1`.

Comment: @charlietfl i have no other way of ultimately distinguishing one element from another... :/

Comment: Is `divs` guaranteed to be ordered by `id`. That is, are we searching on an ordered array? EDIT: Both examples are ordered. But I don't know if `getElementsbyID` will preserve the order of created elements, so I don't know if `divs` will actually be in numeric order.

Comment: @charlietfl i'm making these elements draggable. the underlying issue is that my script is throwing the "parameter 1 is not of type node" error when i use `event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html')`. but i'll very likely end up needing them to have `id`s in the future anyways

Comment: @Qwertycrackers i think i understand your question, and the answer is no. the `div`s aren't necessarily in their correct order. the quantity of `div`s and all of their `id`s are both variables that could be any quantity or any number respectively

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we're talking about algorithmic complexity, your implementation is `O(n)` worst case. If you want to do better, you're probably going to need to employ a more appropriate data structure to store your IDs.

Something like a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)/[min heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap) would be a little better, but you also said that your relatively simple loop is already too complex - you'd have to be willing to find a good library or write them up yourself and that's not necessarily more simple. I won't write up an implementation here, because I think that's out of the scope of a post like this.

Assuming we have this concept of 'free' IDs and 'taken' IDs, and we're calling `insert` when we 'free' up an ID, and `pop` when we 'take' an ID, using the above DS allows us to drop worst case complexity down to `O(logn)`, as opposed to traversing the entire array. It would look something like this (omitting the actual `minHeap` implementation):

```
function takeLowestAvailableID() {
    return minHeap.pop();
}

function freeID(int freed) {
    minHeap.push(freed);
}
```

Note that these are  **worst case**   *runtime*  complexities, and that we haven't even talked about memory considerations

It's difficult to make an end-all, be-all suggestion without knowing more about your application and how your data is coming into existence. If you are only storing IDs from 1-50 and 99% of the time, your application only ever uses 1-10, it might be worth just sticking with the function you have now.

Comment: unfortunately i understand next to nothing about Big O notation. however, i believe the issue with your solution is that it does not take into account the fact that, hypothetically, you could create, say, 20 `divs` and then remove, say, 6 of those 20 `divs` "randomly", leaving you with an array of "taken" IDs like such: [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18, 19, 20]; you would still have to traverse this array to figure out which is the lowest possible number that isn't assigned. furthermore, you could end up in a scenario whereby 100 `divs` were created and, say... (cont'd)

Comment: 60 of them were removed at "random". the quantity of elements that can be created is indefinite and not limited in any way

Comment: Priority queues / heaps handle that. What the data structure does is allow you to always remove the SMALLEST element. Imagine if we had 5 IDs total. We use up 0, 1. The top of our priority queue is now 2. If we need to find the next smallest ID, we only need to look at the top of the priority queue. On the other hand, if we need to free up 0 for instance, then we push it back onto the priority queue. The queue will handle restructuring itself to have 0 end up on the top, so the next time we call takeLowestAvailableID, we get 0.

Comment: This is all under the assumption of course that you're ONLY using the SMALLEST element EVERY time you need to pick up a new ID. If there are situations where you need to assign a RANDOM new ID (from somewhere in the middle of the pack), then the queue would not work. If that's the case, my apologies!

Comment: okay, i think i understand what you're saying. i think it would be just as much work to maintain an array (i.e. add and remove `ids` from it every single time an element is created or removed from the page). i simply want to assign the element an `id` when it is created and then basically forget about it. have you taken a look at David Calhoun's answer above? would it be more efficient than constantly updating arrays to reduce the complexity of finding the lowest possible number which isn't taken?

Comment: Like I said, it's difficult to suggest a definite solution because I'm not entirely sure what your app is doing. If the amount of elements you anticipate is small (I'm guessing that's the case), David's answer is probably fine - you won't even notice the performance hit.  If it's large, you always use the lowest number available, AND you need to 'free' up IDs later, it might be worth looking into heaps/priority queues. If it's large, and you need be able to take randomly (from the middle) and the next lowest, David's answer might be best. It's a game of trade-offs - pick the right one for you.

Comment: My more functional approach traverses arrays a few times, so it's probably less efficient, but the O complexity of those sorts of operations is trivial.  The DOM manipulation is what usually kills performance.  Just dealing with small arrays of numbers is pretty much negligible.

Comment: @DavidCalhoun thanks again for all the input guys <3

Comment: i actually think this is the best solution now that i really think about it

Answer (score 2):

This is a more functional approach, it should do what you need.  It basically takes advantage of sparse arrays.

```js
// Find all DOM elements with ids in the container.
const idElements = document.body.querySelectorAll('#container div[id]');

// Get all ids from the DOM elements.
// Note: first have to convert to a real array ([...idElements])
const allIds = [...idElements].map(domElement => parseInt(domElement.id));

// Filter out non-numbers.
const numericIds = allIds.filter(id => Number.isInteger(id));

// Creates a sparse array, e.g. [undefined, true, undefined].
// (The array index of undefined values are available id slots)
const arrayWithGaps = numericIds.reduce((accum, val) => {
  accum[val] = true;
  return accum;
}, []);

// Find the first empty index - this will be the lowest ID available.
const lowestAvailableId = arrayWithGaps.findIndex(val => typeof val === 'undefined');

console.log(lowestAvailableId);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="0"></div>
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
  <div id="5"></div>
  <div id="16"></div>
  <div id="22"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: if `reduce` is a bit foreign or less readable, you could use forEach instead.  Actually, maybe it makes more sense here anyway:

```js
const arrayWithGaps = [];
numericIds.forEach(id => arrayWithGaps[id] = true);
```

Comment: all of the IDs will be numerical, so no need to filter `allIds`. for the reduce method, i'm lost as to how that's working/what exactly it's doing. you're assigning the value of `true` to `array[NumericalValueOfCurrentID]`. so, if i understand this correctly, if the first ID were `3`, it would create an array like so: [undefined, undefined, true]?! am i understanding this?

Comment: Reduce is a weird concept but it's a really powerful function.  You could also use a forEach to achieve the same thing if that makes more sense!  Almost, since it's 0-indexed it would be [undefined, undefined, undefined, true].  But I think you get the idea!  (I edited the code to provide a simpler forEach, which maybe makes more sense in this case)

Comment: it wasn't reduce that was confusing me, it was how the array is filling in the blanks with `undefined` values if you assign a value to an index that isn't 0. i really like this solution!!

Comment: Ahh cool, yeah sparse arrays are a handy thing to take advantage of sometimes!

Comment: i had never even heard of "sparse" arrays until now. i'll have to read abotu them tomo since it's time to go watch a movie so i can get to bed at a decent hour lol. thanks so much <3

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```js
let el = document.querySelectorAll('div:not(#container)');
let elArray = [...el].map(i=>i.getAttribute('id'));
var arrayLength = Math.max.apply(Math, elArray);
var missing = [];

for ( var i = 1; i <= arrayLength; i++ ) {
    if ( elArray.indexOf(i.toString()) < 0 ) {
        missing.push(i);
    }
}
missing = missing.map(item => parseInt(item));
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, missing);
console.log('Lowest possible id is: ', min);

// Create element
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.setAttribute('id', min);
var container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(div);
document.getElementById(min.toString()).innerHTML = min;
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="3">3</div>
  <div id="4">4</div>
  <div id="5">5</div>
  <div id="16">16</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly straightforward approach that doesn't require fancy logic

```js
const elems = document.querySelector('#container').children;

const getNextId = (els) => {
  let next = 1;
  if (elems) {// skip this if no existing elements
    const set = new Set([...els].map(({id}) => +id));
    while (set.has(next)) {
      next++;
    }
  }
  return next;
}

console.log('Next id: ', getNextId(elems))
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="3">3</div>
  <div id="4">4</div>
  <div id="5">5</div>
  <div id="16">16</div>
  <div id="22">22</div>
</div>
```

Comment: simple i like it. i know next to nothing about the Set object. however, i have read about it very briefly in the past. that'll def go on my list of things to learn

Comment: Not supported in all browsers but logic is same if you use an array also

Comment: No actually they don't. Set has it's own accessor and iterator methods

Comment: map is working on the array that is created from the destructured node list and is in turn being passed into the set